# How do I fix the error "Expected Expression"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I was making an app on `Xcode ( Objective C)` and I really am not able to find a way to fix it

Can somebody please help me with this?

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "DistanceGetter/DGDistanceRequest.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *startLocation;
    @property (nonatomic) DGDistanceRequest *req;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endLocationA;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *distanceA;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endLocationB;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceB;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endLocationC;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceC;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *calculateButton;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    - (IBAction)calculateButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    self.calculateButton.enabled=NO;
    self.req = [DGDistanceRequest alloc];
    NSString *start = self.startLocation.text;
    NSString *destA = self.endLocationA.text;
    NSString *destB = self.endLocationA.text;
    NSString *destC = self.endLocationA.text;
    NSArray *dests = @[destA,destB,destC];


    self.req = [self.req initWithLocationDescriptions:dests 
    sourceDescription:start];
    self.req.callback= void(ˆNSArray *responses)
    self.distanceC.text=@"callback";
    self.calculateButton.enabled = YES;
    self.req=nil;
```

When I make it ˆvoid(NSArray.....) it gives even more errors

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! If you could edit your question with the code directly instead of screenshot it would be great!

Comment: You should edit your question to include your code as text, not as an image

Comment: Please provide details about problem you are facing and put your program here in question instead of image.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo :
`void(^...` should be `^void(...` - the error is somewhat misleading, and it seems strange than Xcode didn’t suggest a „Fix-it”.

Anyway, I recommend http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/ to remind yourself with block syntax.